# can io_uring system call or any other system call be used by an application to transfer data from a socket to file while doing a zero copy?

Tags: operating-system, system-calls

is there any system call that can copy data from a socket to a file? I looked into sendfile system call and I see that the input_fd has to be a file descriptor so I was wondering if there is any system call an application can leverage to do zero copy when receiving the data from a socket and storing it in a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This looks like a duplicate of [Understanding sendfile() and splice()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8626263/2732969)) This question asker here wants to know if data read from a socket can be zero-copied to a file and the mention of `io_uring` strongly suggests the asker is specifically interested in Linux.

In short yes, it is possible to receive from a socket and output to a file without having to make unnecessary duplicate copies by using [splice(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/splice.2.html) on Linux but it's not trivial - the socket must be attached to one end of the pipe and the file's descriptor to the other end. Since the 5.7 Linux kernel [`io_uring` also supports a splice operation](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/7d67af2c013402537385dae343a2d0f6a4cb3bfd) so it too can do zero copy from a socket to a file via a pipe.

Comment: I am looking to see if there exists a system call that can do a zero copy from a socket to a local file? so there are two descriptors in my question 1) a socket descriptor 2) a file descriptor. To give a more concrete example, Imagine a web server that receives messages at particular socket and it needs to store them to a local file. can the web server do a zero copy?

Comment: It requires one the file descriptor to be a pipe.

Comment: yes sendfile cannot have socket descriptor as input_fd(input file descriptor). pipe takes two file descriptors as parameters (input_fd, output_fd) and one of them has to be pipe. In my case I want the input_fd to be a socket. so the question is can a pipe be the socket? and can it work as expected? I don't know the answer to that. That's why I posted my question here

Comment: can you explain how socket can be a pipe? an example may be along with how to do it using splice?

Comment: yeah but there must be a reason why sendfile must have restricted it. so I want to understand those

Comment: From a historic perspective `sendfile` was first. On Linux it was designed to optimise getting pages out of a populated page cache efficiently but is not generic hence the restrictions (this is alluded to in this [LKML sendfile thread](https://yarchive.net/comp/linux/sendfile.html)). `splice` came later and is more flexible (but more complicated) and was generic enough to entirely support `sendfile`. If you [follow the links in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8626372/2732969) on another question you will see an example of how you can read socket/pipe/write file with `splice`.

Comment: got it. do you know what is packet_mmap? online says it is a syscall but I cannot see it on my ubuntu and there is no man page either.

Comment: I think we might be getting off-topic but a quick google quickly led to https://stackoverflow.com/q/43193889/2732969 where the top answer even says "Many interfaces to the linux kernel are not well documented" :-). It looks like you're going down rabbit hole (so I hope you enjoy the journey :-) but so I'll bail out and leave you with a link to https://blog.cloudflare.com/sockmap-tcp-splicing-of-the-future/ to distract you further...

Comment: yes. thanks for pointing out all the useful resources and your commentary(besides the sarcastic ones) does help.