# would sendfile be better if we have to write data that is already in memory?

Tags: c, sockets, sendfile

i am having some data in **user space memory buffer** that i want to send through socket. i was reading about **zero copy** in Linux, was wondering it is possible to use it in this case or any optimisation possible here.

```
char buff[buffer_size]; // buffer already in memory (user space)
while (condition) {
  buff[(i++) % buffer_size] = 1; // do some changes in buffer
  write(sockfd, buff, buffer_size); // can we use sendfile here? would it give benefit?
}
```

Comment: The hint is in the name: `sendfile` sends *files*. It bypasses the file -> OS buffer -> userspace -> kernel -> network stack mess and just goes, effectively, file -> kernel -> network stack. It can't help if you already have something in userspace.

Comment: @tadman what i understand above code is going through 
data (userspace) -> kernel -> network stack
i am asking if it possible to remove any step in my case?

Comment: There's really no step to remove here if you've already loaded the data in memory.

Comment: @tadman was thinking like, directly having block of memory in kernel, so steps would look like data (kernel) -> network stack (similar to what sendfile does)

Comment: You don't get a "block of memory in the kernel" unless you're writing code that runs in the kernel. It's *always* userspace memory, especially if you're manipulating it. You can't change arbitrary kernel memory from userspace code.

Comment: The first question is what problem are you trying to solve here? Do you have a *measurable performance problem* you need to resolve?

Comment: @tadman no, i was looking into working for kafka and this use-case popped up.
thanks.

Comment: Theres's only so much you can optimize here. If this data was in a memory mapped file then *maybe* you could treat it as just a regular `sendfile` call, but that's rarely a viable path. These days most data is encrypted in transit, which means you need to feed this through a TLS stream anyway.

Comment: See: https://docs.kernel.org/networking/packet_mmap.html and [Sending data with PACKET_MMAP and PACKET_TX_RING is slower than "normal" (without)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43193889/5382650)

Comment: @tadman Linux does have [`memfd_create()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/memfd_create.2.html): "unlike a regular file, it lives in RAM and has a volatile backing storage..."  Knowing Linux and glibc, it could just be a hack that uses a `mmap()`'d file in a `tmpfs` filesystem, but there is a possibility it actually does something useful under the hood.